# Filling an empty dataframe by assignment via loc selection with tuple indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

Why does this work?

```
a=pd.DataFrame()
a.loc[1,2]=0

>
     2
1  0.0
```

And, this does not work?

```
a=pd.DataFrame()
a.loc[(1,2),2]=0
>
KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'
```

The latter is what I would like to do. I will be filling the values by assignment via loc selection with tuple specified index, from a dataframe with no values, 0 rows, 0 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a tuple as index will work if your dataframe already has a multi-index:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define multi-index
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[],[]], names=['first', 'second'])
# or
# index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([], names=['first', 'second']) 

a = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
a.loc[(1,2), 2]=0

#                 2
# first second     
# 1.0   2.0     0.0
```

Comment: That's not a great example because the dataframe doesn't start out as totally empty... A better comparison would utilize an empty MultiIndex.

Comment: Yes, I would like an empty multiindex. But pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([], names=['first', 'second']) gives me TypeError: Cannot infer number of levels from empty list.

Comment: @ConanG It works for me (in Pandas 0.20.3). Do you have another version of Pandas?

Comment: `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[],[]], names=['first', 'second'])` works

Comment: My version is '0.19.2'. But I won't be able to update it.

Comment: @ConanG Try BallpointBen's suggestion (see the latest answer edit)

Comment: Looks odd. But it works on 0.19.2. I'll take it. Thanks guys.

Comment: I tried to answer this question when you first started with a non-empty dataframe.  When I came back, you had the same exact answer as I had come up with...  What I'm trying to say is, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Julien's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50277751/2336654) as it feels less like magic.  All of these are efforts to set a 2 level multiindex.

### `set_index` with empty arrays

```
i = np.array([])
a = pd.DataFrame().set_index([i, i])
a.loc[(1, 2), 2] = 0

a

           2
1.0 2.0  0.0
```

---

Slightly more concise

```
a = pd.DataFrame().set_index([np.array([])] * 2)
a.loc[(1, 2), 2] = 0
```

---

### `pd.concat`

```
a = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame()] * 2, keys=[1, 2])
a.loc[(1, 2), 2] = 0

a

       2
1 2  0.0
```